# How to get all information from Global Address List (GAL) from Microsoft Exchange, using EWS Managed API?

Tags: exchange-server, office365, exchangewebservices, gal

I need to get all contacts from Microsoft Exchange.. Those contacts are also saved in **Office365 -> People -> Directory**. Many thx for help!

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't solve your problems for you. People are happy to help but you need to put in a good faith effort to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ResolveName("SMTP:") API to retrieve all the contacts from Global Address List, the limitation of such is it only returns the top 100 from the query operation.

Your Managed EWS code works similar to

```
        var nameResolutionCollection = service.ResolveName("SMTP:");
        foreach(var item in nameResolutionCollection)
        {
            // your code in here
        }
```

Find out more information from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563518%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx.

Comment: The output is like:
Horna Milena;SMTP:hornamilenamatejskok@gmail.com <br>
Stanislav Kopal;SIP:kopal@skoktest.onmicrosoft.com <br>
Matej Skok;smtp:programator@skoktest.onmicrosoft.com 
Novak Filip;SMTP:filipnovakmatejskok@gmail.com 
Skoq Andrej;smtp:skoqandrejmatejsko@skoktest.onmicrosoft.com 
Slana Sara;SMTP:slanasaramatejskok@gmail.com 

But it returns only one email in every iteration in foreach loop. I need to get all emails of every person (especially I need to get the SMTP email of every person).

Comment: >when you say "get all emails of every person", did you mean you could have multiple email addresses for a single person?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There can be more addresses for every user in Exchange. There are addressess of 3 types:
a) SMTP
b) smtp
c) sip

I need to get the SMTP address of every person in People -> Dictionary

Comment: Not sure if it works, but have you tried service.ResolveName("SIP:")?

Comment: Hi, I have already solved it. 
`if(nr.Contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].ToString().Contains("SMTP:"))
                { 

                    pom_SMTPemail = nr.Contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].ToString();

                }`